# Assign text read from file in network to TextView in Android fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to read a file over the network and assign the returned text to a TextView widget of a Fragment. The file is read in an Async thread, after being called by a method in ManActivity. The codes are given below:

```
MainActivity.java (relevant part):

public void myClickHandler(View view){
    ConnectivityManager connmngr=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo networkinfo=connmngr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();
    if(networkinfo!=null && networkinfo.isConnected()){
        new Fragment_2().new DownloadWebpageTask(ma).execute(stringurl);
    }else{
        textview.setText("No network connection available");
    }
}
}

//Called by the OnPostExecute() method
public void displayText(String result){
    DateFormat df=DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
    java.util.Date d=new java.util.Date();
    String display=result + " " + df.format(d);
    Log.d("DOWNLOAD",display);
    textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.web_text);
    textview.setText(display);
}


Fragment_2.java
public class Fragment_2 extends Fragment {

private static final String DEBUG_TAG="HttpExample";
MainActivity ma;
String result;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
    TextView textview=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_text);
    textview.setText(result);
    return rootView;
}

//Call AsyncTask to create a new, background network thread which is separate from the UI thread
public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    MainActivity ma;

    DownloadWebpageTask(MainActivity ma){
        this.ma=ma;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            result=downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            result="Exception while reading the text";
         }
         return result;
     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        ma.displayText(result);
    }
    //downloadUrl fetches and processes the web page content. After  processing, it returns a result string.
    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException{
        InputStream is=null;
        String str=null;

        try{
            URL url=new URL(myurl);
            Log.d("URL:",url.toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(20000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            Log.d("TRY DOWNLOAD","Inside try block of downloadUrl");
            //Start the query
            conn.connect();
            int response=conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"The response is : " + response);
            BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            while((str=in.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(str);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }finally{
            //input stream should be closed after the app has finished using it
            if(is!=null){
                is.close();
            }
        }   
    }
}
}
```

onPostExecute() calls the displayText() method in the MainActivity. However, i need the text to appear in a textview of the fragment. So I need to change the code in the onCreateView() method of Fragment_2.java, I guess.

But I don't know how to do so exactly. Please help.

Comment: With this code, currently I am getting NullPointerException in the line textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.web_text); of displayText of MainActivity.java

Comment: did you setContentView in onCreate() ?

Comment: yes..but that was setContentView(R.layout.activity_main),

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in this code

```
public void myClickHandler(View view){
    ConnectivityManager connmngr=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo networkinfo=connmngr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();
    if(networkinfo!=null && networkinfo.isConnected()){
        new Fragment_2().new DownloadWebpageTask(ma).execute(stringurl);
    }else{
        textview.setText("No network connection available");
    }
}
```

change this line

`new Fragment_2().new DownloadWebpageTask(ma).execute(stringurl);` to

`new Fragment_2().new DownloadWebpageTask(this.getActivity()).execute(stringurl);`

You are passing a new activity that is not the current instance but another one, you need to pass a reference to main activity that this fragment is part of.

I hope this fix your issue